# How to prevent Matlab filebrowser to do any changes in filesystem?

Tags: debian, matlab

I get significant amount of artifacts in Matlab 2016a and 2016b, which are damaging my filesystem, etc random cursor movements moving my `Documents` folder to `Pictures`. I do not want that such actions are possible in Matlab because it is not stable in Linux.

OS: Debian 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6 of backports
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Matlab: 2016a, 2016b prerelease

Comment: You're running the process as yourself, and so it naturally has permissions to move and remove your files. Is this a feature request for Matlab, or a request to find a way to run the Matlab file browser in a way that prevents it from modifying your files?

Comment: I am thinking a one liner that could prevent it so latter.

Comment: I don't use the product, so I have an ignorant question: what do you want a "file browser" to do, if not manage your files?

Comment: Nothing actually. Just disable it as one liner would be great.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. My kneejerk reaction is: "so don't run the file browser" ? Or is the file browser some feature or part of the overall product?

Comment: Yes, it is standard part of Matlab but buggy in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent MathWorks about 50 bug reports Q3-Q4 2016. 
They acknowledged the problems, and connected me to several cases in their system. 
However, I am not convinced that they have sufficient resources to fix the cases in the short-term.

They have promised to pay attention to the bugs existing in MATLAB 2016b/... in Debian Linux. 
However, they have not provided me any reliable plan for the fixes. 
They also have not provided sufficient expertise for me about the cases. 
So I cannot provide any estimate of the schedule when the bugs of MATLAB will be fixed in Debian Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the proprietary software with firejail.
Firejail allows to configure the access to folders, ports and devices.
https://github.com/netblue30/firejail